# Multiple Substring Charindex

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, substring, charindex

I am trying to extract strings from a column to show which are the FROM Tables and JOIN Tables. the complete string consists of one FROM Table and multiple JOIN Tables. Here is a sample of a string:

```sql
FROM [TABLEOWNER] .[load_XT_Customer_test] load_XT_Customer_test
INNER JOIN [TABLEOWNER].[load_xt_orders_test] load_xt_orders_test ON load_xt_customer_test.customer_id=load_xt_orders_test.customer_id
INNER JOIN [TABLEOWNER].[load_XT_Orders] load_XT_Orders ON 
load_xt_customer_test.customer_id=load_xt_orders.customer_id
INNER JOIN [TABLEOWNER].[load_xt_order_details_test] load_xt_order_details_test
ON load_xt_customer_test.customer_id=load_xt_order_details_test.customer_id
```

My problem here is that there is no unique character to separate the strings, how can I dynamically extract the single join tables?

I tested it with:

```sql
SELECT st_where 
        ,SUBSTRING(st_where 
       ,CHARINDEX('] ',st_where,1)+1 
       ,ABS(CHARINDEX(' ',st_where,CHARINDEX('] ',st_where,1)+1) 
-CHARINDEX(']',st_where,1)-1))
AS FromTable
       ,SUBSTRING(st_where 
       ,CHARINDEX('JOIN [TABLEOWNER].[',st_where,1)+19 
       ,ABS(CHARINDEX(' ',st_where,CHARINDEX('JOIN [TABLEOWNER].[',st_where,1)+19) 
       -CHARINDEX('JOIN [TABLEOWNER].[',st_where,1)-20))
AS JoinTable
,SUBSTRING(st_where 
       ,CHARINDEX('=',st_where,1)+59
       ,ABS(CHARINDEX(' ',st_where,CHARINDEX('=',st_where,1)+59) 
       -CHARINDEX('=',st_where,1)-60))
AS JoinTable2
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. Sample data and expected results will help us help you here. I also really recommend uses aliases, it'll make your queries far more succinct.

Comment: Simplify the problem, and show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images). [mcve]

Comment: The data can be FROM all of these tables, the returned columns will be whatever you have specified in your SELECT statement. Columns from different tables will remain separate (unless you are using COALESCE or similar). If you need to specifify which columns were in which table then you can rename them in the output eg ```SELECT load_XT_Customer_test.ColName as [Table_1_ColName] FROM load_XT_Customer_test ```

Comment: Are you trying to do string manipulation via SQL on another SQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```sql
DECLARE @st_where nvarchar(max) =
N'
FROM [TABLEOWNER] .[load_XT_Customer_test] load_XT_Customer_test
INNER JOIN [TABLEOWNER].[load_xt_orders_test] load_xt_orders_test ON load_xt_customer_test.customer_id=load_xt_orders_test.customer_id
INNER JOIN [TABLEOWNER].[load_XT_Orders] load_XT_Orders ON 
load_xt_customer_test.customer_id=load_xt_orders.customer_id
INNER JOIN [TABLEOWNER].[load_xt_order_details_test] load_xt_order_details_test
ON load_xt_customer_test.customer_id=load_xt_order_details_test.customer_id
';

SELECT
    TableName =
        SUBSTRING
        (
            SS.[value], 
            CharStart.pos + 1, 
            CharEnd.pos - CharStart.pos + 1
        )
FROM STRING_SPLIT
(
    -- Replace delimiter phrase with a single character
    -- so we can use STRING_SPLIT
    -- or use a more general string splitter
    REPLACE(@st_where, N'INNER JOIN', NCHAR(256)), 
    NCHAR(256)
) AS SS
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
    (
        -- Find the start of the table name
        CHARINDEX(N'.[', SS.[value], 1)
    )
) AS CharStart (pos)
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
    (
        -- Find the end of the table name
        CHARINDEX(N']', SS.[value], CharStart.pos)
    )
) AS CharEnd (pos);
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=74173e291d27eade0addda6a19cef58a)

The general idea is to split the input string on the phrase "INNER JOIN" then locate the table names using  ".[" and "]" as delimiters.